# Bash script that displays and kills selected processes

Tags: bash, signal-handling

This is my first Bash script and I decided to use what I've learned so far to help manage stray processes while I develop in my *nix environs.

I've tested the script extensively and it seems to work (there may be some things I have not caught yet).

If I could get some critiques/tips on the script that would be great.

I named the file `process` and placed it in my ~/bin folder so that I could execute it like any other program.

```
#!/bin/bash

# kill processes using SIGQUIT signal -- still in testing

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

function _usage_notice {
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [ help | show | destroy ] [ arg(s)... ]"
}

function _usage_summary {
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [ action ] [ arg(s)... ]

    Summary
    -------
    This script is designed to send a quit signal event to a
    running program. If multiple instances of that program
    exist, they are all sent the same signal.

    Action      Description
    ------      -----------
    show        Shows current processes for current user.

    kill
    destroy     Sends SIGQUIT signal to given process if
            given process exists.

    help        Outputs this help text.
"
}

function _usage_processes {
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [ show ] [ user | root | unsorted | sorted | less ]

    Examples
    --------
    $PROGNAME show
        Executes 'ps' with the format 'pid,user,comm'
    $PROGNAME show user
        Executes 'ps' and outputs 'user' owned processes
    $PROGNAME show root
        Executes 'ps' and outputs 'root' owned processes
    $PROGNAME show [ unsorted | all ]
        'all' and 'unsorted' are synonymous and displays all processes
    $PROGNAME show sorted
        Executes 'ps' and outputs 'all' processes in sorted order by user
    $PROGNAME show less
        Executes 'ps' and pipes 'all' output to 'less' if 'less' exists
"
}

function _usage_destroy {
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [ destroy ] [ command(s)... ]

    Examples
    --------
    $PROGNAME destroy nautilus
        Sends the SIGQUIT signal to the process 'nautilus'
    $PROGNAME destroy [ program(s)... ]
        You can pass multiple programs all at once as well.
    $PROGNAME destroy nautilus bash pithos firefox
        Sends the SIGQUIT signal to given processes
"
}

function _usage_help {
echo "Usage: $PROGNAME [ help ] [ show | destroy | help ]

    Examples
    --------
    $PROGNAME
        Outputs basic usage
    $PROGNAME help
        Outputs usage summary
    $PROGNAME help [ show | destroy | help ]
        Outputs usage information for given action
"
}

function _usage_full {
    case $1 in
        "show")         _usage_processes ;;
        "destroy"|"kill")   _usage_destroy ;;
        "help")         _usage_help ;;
        *)          echo "Invalid argument given to action help." ;;
    esac
}

# test if a valid action was given
function _is_valid_action {
    case $1 in
        "destroy"|"kill")   echo valid  ;;
        "show")         echo valid  ;;
        "help")         echo valid  ;;
        *)          echo ""     ;;
    esac
}


# test if action has no arguments
function _input_is_empty {
    while [[ 0 -lt "$#" ]]; do
        if [[ -n $(_is_valid_action $1) ]]; then
            shift
            if [[ -n $(_is_valid_action "$1") ]]; then
                echo valid
                break
            fi
            continue
        elif [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
            echo valid
            break
        else
            echo ""
            break
        fi
    done
}

# show current processes according to given arguments
function _processes {
    case "$1" in
        "user")         ps -U $USER -o pid,tty,user,comm ;;
        "root")         ps -U root -o pid,tty,user,comm ;;
        "all"|"unsorted")   ps -A -o pid,tty,user,comm ;;
        "sorted")       ps -A --sort=user -o pid,tty,user,comm ;;
        "less")         if [[ -n $(which less) ]]; then
                        ps -A --sort=user -o pid,tty,user,comm | less
                    else
                        echo "'less' is not installed."
                    fi ;;
        *)          ps -o pid,user,comm ;;
    esac
}

# send to quit signal to given processes
function _destroy {
    while [[ 0 -lt "$#" ]]; do
        pid=$(pgrep $1)

        if [[ -z "$pid" ]]; then
            echo "Process '$1' does not exist."
            exit 2 
        fi

        for item in $pid; do
            kill -SIGQUIT $pid 
            echo "Destroyed process '$item' named '$1'"
        done

        shift
    done
}

function _prompt {
    echo "Warning! This function uses pattern matching!"
    echo "This is DANGEROUS because multiple processes may be selected!"
    read -p "Are you sure you want to continue? [y/yes/n/no]> " answer
    case $answer in
        "y"|"yes")  clear
                echo "You were Warned! Starting in 5 seconds..."
                sleep 5 
                return ;;
        "n"|"no")   exit 2 ;;
    esac
}

case $1 in
    "show") 
        shift
        _processes "$@"
        ;;

    "destroy"|"kill")   
        if [[ -z $(_input_is_empty "$@") ]]; then
            echo "No arguments were given to destroy."
            exit 1
        fi

        shift
        _prompt
        _destroy "$@"
        ;;

    "help") 
        if [[ -z $(_input_is_empty "$@") ]]; then
            _usage_summary
            exit 0
        fi

        shift
        _usage_full "$@"
        ;;

    *) # default
        _usage_notice 
        exit 1 
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's very nice that you have separated each distinct functionality into functions, nicely done. Some improvements are possible.

#### Use the exit code, Luke

This function prints "valid" if the input is valid, or empty string if invalid:

> ```
> function _is_valid_action {
>     case $1 in
>         "destroy"|"kill")   echo valid  ;;
>         "show")         echo valid  ;;
>         "help")         echo valid  ;;
>         *)          echo ""     ;;
>     esac
> }
> ```

It would be better to use the exit code instead, like this:

```
function _is_valid_action {
    case $1 in
        destroy|kill|show|help) return 0 ;;
        *) return 1
    esac
}
```

You will need to change the callers accordingly. Instead this:

> ```
>     if [[ -n $(_is_valid_action $1) ]]; then
> ```

Change to:

```
    if _is_valid_action $1; then
```

Which happens to be simpler.

Adjust `_input_is_empty` following the same logic.

#### Double-quote path variables

It's recommended to double-quote all path variables to prevent globbing and word splitting, for example here, put `$0` in `"$0"`:

> ```
> PROGNAME=$(basename $0)
> ```

#### No need to double-quote literal strings

In this code, the double-quoting is a bit awkward for the cases:

> ```
>     case $1 in
>         "show")         _usage_processes ;;
>         "destroy"|"kill")   _usage_destroy ;;
>         "help")         _usage_help ;;
>         *)          echo "Invalid argument given to action help." ;;
>     esac
> ```

You could write simpler as:

```
    case $1 in
        show)         _usage_processes ;;
        destroy|kill)   _usage_destroy ;;
        help)         _usage_help ;;
        *)          echo "Invalid argument given to action help." ;;
    esac
```

#### Minor things

It's not a problem,
it's just a bit unusual to print large multiline blocks of text using `echo`. It can get troublesome if you need to embed double-quotes.
The commonly used alternative is a *here document*, like this:

```
cat << EOF
Usage: $PROGNAME [ destroy ] [ command(s)... ]

    Examples
    --------
    $PROGNAME destroy nautilus
        Sends the SIGQUIT signal to the process 'nautilus'
    $PROGNAME destroy [ program(s)... ]
        You can pass multiple programs all at once as well.
    $PROGNAME destroy nautilus bash pithos firefox
        Sends the SIGQUIT signal to given processes
EOF
```